# setIcon NavigationView из asset

Tags: android

Привет, создаю

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"/>
```

И пытаюсь запихнуть туда пункты меню,

```
   AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
                InputStream istr = null;
                try {
                    istr = assetManager.open("image.jpg");
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(istr);
                Drawable icon = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap);

                menu.add("Title").setIcon(icon);
```

Картинки лежат в assets но на их месте отображаются темно серые квадратики

Пробовал переместить их в drawable

```
menu.add("title").setIcon(R.drawable.img);
```

Результат абсолютно аналогичен... Что это может быть? Неужели в стандартную уже NavigationView нельзя запихнуть растровые картинки?

Comment: попробуйте .png

Comment: пробовал... не помогло

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31394265/navigation-drawer-item-icon-not-showing-original-colour ?

Comment: Tint работает коректно, но он перекрашивает весь блок, а не дает желаемый результат

Answer (score 1):

Картинки ассетов должны лежать в папке assets, а не в папке drawable. При этом папку надо создать с помощью студии, а не вручную на уровне ОС. Попробуйте так:

```
assetManager = getResources().getAssets();
InputStream stream; 
try {
String someimage = ImageName.substring(0,15);
stream = assetManager.open("image.jpg");
Drawable flag = Drawable.createFromStream(stream, someimage);
imageView.setImageDrawable(flag);
}
```

Как другой вариант - это использовать стороннюю библиотеку, например, [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/).